# Application not working on Windows XP, despite using XP toolset. Troubleshoting ideas needed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, dependencies, windows-xp, compatibility

I'm developing a dll library. My solution (cmake core, Visual Studio sln generated) consists of a few static .lib projects that are used to build this dll and the dll project itself. There are also some 3rd party dependencies (boost, nana and some more). I'm using hell dependencies manager (https://rilis.io/projects/hell) to download my dependencies. I know it's not widely used, but to put it short it is just a simple tool that after reading config file downloads dependencies using git, generates projects using cmake and compiles using the requested generator.

I need my dll to support Windows XP. I develop on Windows 10 machine and I copy the dll to Windows XP SP3 machine, which is where I run the tests. However my dll fails to load on windows xp. LoadLibrary returns nullptr. The name and architecture are matching. I'm not getting any system error, just the pointer returned is nullptr. I used to have system errors but I eliminated them by switching to functions that were present in Windows XP API. I enabled Snapping and ran profiling in DependencyWalker. I got errors about

```
    api-ms-win-core-synch-*
    api-ms-win-core-fibers-*
    api-ms-win-core-localization-*
```

failing to load (probably also through dynamic loading during dll initialization. I found out its Windows XP compatibility issue. I figured out that I need to build my module using v140_xp toolset. Cmake provides options to specify toolset and hell is supposed to propagate this setting to build other dependencies using provided toolset. To the best of my knowledge about hell, cmake and visual studio that should be the case. However my dll still fails to load and DependencyWalker + snapping still show the same failed load attempts.

I want to know whether I missed something in my approach or if the toolset setting is not propagated to all static libraries. The second one could cause one or more of dependencies to be compiled with non xp toolset, resulting in linking with non-xp cruntime (I'm linking statically with crt - MTd/MT) and failed dependency.

I need some ideas that would help me troubleshot this issue. Anyone knows how I can check which obj or lib that my dll consists of could add dependency to non-xp API? Or maybe someone has an idea what I could have missed when building my module?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you installed the correct visual studio 2015 runtime on the machine?

Comment: As a test only: If you obtain (build and/or download) all your dependencies and DLLs as dynamic libraries then you can use DependencyWalker on each DLL independently to find the offending ones.

Comment: @AlanBirtles on which machine? Im building on Windows 10 and I have v140_xp toolset here. On the Windows XP machine that I test my app on I dont think any dlls other than system ones are needed. Or am I wrong? Windows XP machine has SP 3 - I forgot to mention

Comment: @MarcinK. Your application *always* (well, with *very* few, *very* rare exceptions) needs to install the Visual Studio redistributable run-time libraries that match the Visual Studio version that was used to build the application, along with the application itself. Other compilers have similar requirements. Without the correct runtime libraries, the application won't work.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685

Comment: @JesperJuhl
Thanks for your comments. However when linking with Static CRT (/MT, /MTd) shouldn't that provide the application with all the necessary code, other than obligatory system libraries (kernel32.dll etc.)?